# XML not well formed - android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have error on the seconde relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dip"
            **android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
                android:padding="3dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/place_thumbnail"
                    android:layout_width="70dip"
                    android:layout_height="70dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/progressbar" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#10bcc9"
                android:textSize="14dip"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adress"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="phone    :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="website  :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/website"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="rating    :"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:rating="0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_directions" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Gallery
            android:id="@+id/gallery1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

i have checked old posts in the same problem , but i didn't find a similare case 
i will need to find the correct format and also the possibilitys of having this problem

Comment: remove that, you only need that on the base layout

Comment: **android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  why the asterisks? (I can't find a markdown that works but the namespace declaration has asterisks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

Get rid of `**android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**`, you only need to declare this once in every document. You've also commented it out the wrong way. Use `<!--` and `-->` to comment out code.

**Second:**

`style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

**Should be:**

`style="@android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the two asterisks (*) before and after the last line of the RelativeLayout.

Remove `**android:xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">**`. You have already declared the namespace in the LinearLayout anyway, so this line is not needed.